# Apply active state on clicked button only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that changes the active state onClick:

```
render() {
    return(
      <SomeButton
          onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}
          id={someId}
          activeStatus={someId === this.state.active ? "active" : "not active"}
      />
    )
}
```

The function that changes the state:

```
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ active: e.currentTarget.id });
}
```

The state:

```
this.state = {
    active: null
};
```

The button that receives the activeStatus props:

```
export default function SomeButton({ activeStatus }) {

    console.log(activeStatus);

    return (
        // button jsx code
    );
}
```

However, every time I click on the button (I have 3 instances of that button on the page), the activeStatus console.log shows:

I click on button 1:

```
active
not active
not active
```

I click on button 2:

```
active
active
not active
```

I click on button 3:

```
active
active
active
```

I was expecting that the status would toggle depending on the active button which is clicked.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the `console.log` lines are accurate? Add `id` to the the console output.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the entire app with the 3 buttons? It would be easier to find the problem I think.

Comment: Can you include more code for initial render?

Comment: `// button jsx code` it might be important, what this jsx looks like. like on what objects do you attach the `id` and the click-handler passed as `props`

Comment: how about `onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, someId)}`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the state in an array:

```
this.state = {
    active: [false, false, false] // or just: []
};

handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const activeState = [false, false, false]; // or just: []
    activeState[e.currentTarget.index] = true;
    // button index ^^
    this.setState({ active: activeState });
}
```

And just pass the `activeStatus` to the `active` state:

```
activeStatus={this.state.active}
```

Inside your component, bind the active state:

```
<button className={ activeStatus[0] ? 'active' : 'not-active' }>...</button>
<button className={ activeStatus[1] ? 'active' : 'not-active' }>...</button>
<button className={ activeStatus[2] ? 'active' : 'not-active' }>...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `e.target.id` instead of `e.currentTarget.id` and if the button ids are static, then you could put them into your `state` and use the `id` to update a `buttonState` object (one of several ways to handle it).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/olmn9k08m5

Some notes:

- Keep your state consistent (if it's a string, keep it a string, if
  it's an array, keep it any array...etc -- in the example below
  `buttonState` is an `object` and stays an `object`).
- Also, you don't need `e.preventDefault()` unless you're submitting a
  `form` or trying to [block functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
- Always specify the button's `type` ("button" or "submit")

**ShowButton.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SomeButton from "./SomeButton";

const buttons = ["button1", "button2", "button3"];

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    buttonState: {
      button1: "inactive",
      button2: "inactive",
      button3: "inactive"
    }
  };

  handleClick = e => {
    const { id } = e.target; // id="button1","button2" or "button3"
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      buttonState: {
        ...prevState.buttonState, // spread out object
        [id]: prevState.buttonState[id] === "active" ? "inactive" : "active" // use the [id] as an object property (ex: "button1") and set the property's value to "active" or "inactive"
      }
    }));
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Controlling Active Buttons</h1>
      {buttons.map(id => (
        <SomeButton
          key={id}
          id={id}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
          activeStatus={this.state.buttonState[id]}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**SomeButton.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ activeStatus, handleClick, id }) => (
  <div style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
    <button
      type="button"
      style={{ minWidth: 150 }}
      className={`uk-button ${
        activeStatus === "active" ? "uk-button-primary" : null
      }`}
      id={id}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      {activeStatus}
    </button>
  </div>
);
```